# magento custom theme error

Tags: magento, magento2

**trying to create a custom theme with bitnami XAMPP using magento devdocs**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

**I get this error when I try to access the admin panel**

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1130478184

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to first check in your error log number "1130478184" where you exactly know what is the issue. I think from your given link which you refer your issue must be occured from `theme.xml` file's `<preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>` line. You have to try with comment following code in theme.xml file:-

```
<!--media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media-->
```

Comment: can you please accept answer so it helps to another users. Thanks.